# NullPointerException in java when trying to add a float and object to calculation method

Tags: java

I get a NullPointerException in java when I try to add a float and object to my calculation method.

Here is the class that calls the calculation method:

```
public class Server extends Thread {

    FedExRate display = new FedExRate();

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private String clientAddress;
    private String portNumber;
    private String currentTimeStamp;

    //send to client
    private float flatRate;
    private float additionalRate;
    private float weight;

    //read from client
    private String countryName;
    private String type;
    private float boxWeight;

    //message to display on server side
    private String message1;
    private String message2;
    private String message3;
    private String message4;

    // the calculation part
        private float amount;
        private float surcharge;
        private float totalAmount;

        //create object for other class
        FedexSalesManagerDB database = new FedexSalesManagerDB();
        ProvisionedBox box = new ProvisionedBox();
        CompareAndGetRate passingInfo = new CompareAndGetRate();
        DisplayServer callingGui = new DisplayServer();
        Box passBoxTypeName = new Box();
        ShipmentBox shipBox = new ShipmentBox();
        Country passCountryName = new Country();
        FedExBoxRate flatRatePlusArate;
        FedExSalesManager calculation;

        OutputCal clientValues; 

        //boxno
        private int boxno;

        //courierBoxId
        private int CourierBoxId;

        //shipmentId
        private int shipmentId;

        //database data 
        private DatabaseManager dbManager = new DatabaseManager();
        private Connection conn;
        //

        Socket socket;
        // Get input stream to read from client
        DataInputStream in ;

        //setter and getter
    public float getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(float weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }



    public float getFlatRate() {
        return flatRate;
    }

    public void setFlatRate(float flatRate) {
        this.flatRate = flatRate;
    }

    public float getAdditionalRate() {
        return additionalRate;
    }

    public void setAdditionalRate(float additionalRate) {
        this.additionalRate = additionalRate;
    }

    public float getTotalAmount() {
        return totalAmount;
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(float totalAmount) {
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    }

    public String getPortNumber() {
        return portNumber;
    }

    public void setPortNumber(String portNumber) {
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
    }

    public String getCurrentTime() {
        return currentTimeStamp;
    }

    public void setCurrentTime(String currentTime) {
        this.currentTimeStamp = currentTime;
    }

    public String getClientAddress() {
        return clientAddress;
    }

    public void setClientAddress(String clientAddress) {
        this.clientAddress = clientAddress;
    }

    /**
     * This constructor creates bind server to local port and set timeout to
     * 100000 milliseconds
     * 
     * @param port
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Server() throws IOException {

        // Bind to port
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4050);

        // Server will stop listening to request after 100000 milliseconds
        // serverSocket.setSoTimeout(100000);
    }

    /**
     * Overriding run() Continually listen to request
     */
    public void run() {


            try {




                // Display server status and bound port

                //1st message to display
                message1="Server : Waiting for client on port "+ serverSocket.getLocalPort()+ "...";
                System.out.println(message1);



                // Listen and accept client connection to socket
                socket = serverSocket.accept();



                // Display the connected client
                //2nd message to display
                message2="Server : Just connected to "
                        + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
                System.out.println(message2);

                // Get input stream to read from client


                in = new DataInputStream(
                        socket.getInputStream());

                // cast client IP address to String
                clientAddress = in.readUTF();

                System.out.println(clientAddress);
                // cast client port number to String
                portNumber = in.readUTF();

                // get time from the client
                currentTimeStamp = in.readUTF();


                /*//passing data from client to GUI interface
                callingGui.run(clientAddress, portNumber, currentTimeStamp);*/

                // Get output stream to send message to client
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                        socket.getOutputStream());

                // Write to output stream
                //3rd message
                message3="Thank you for connecting to "
                        + socket.getLocalSocketAddress();
                out.writeUTF(message3);

                Boolean compare;
                compare = in.readBoolean();




                if (compare == true) {
                    System.out.println(compare);
                    display.displayGUI();
                    String [] country=display.getNegara();
                    String [] boxtype=display.getType();

                    BoxLoader boxLoad = new BoxLoader();
                    boxLoad.BoxLoad();

                    ObjectOutputStream outobject = new ObjectOutputStream(
                            socket.getOutputStream());
                    //passing the country and boxType array to display at client comboBox
                    outobject.writeObject(country);
                    outobject.writeObject(boxtype);



                    //vector that use to store the rate that get from boxLoader
                    Vector<FedExBoxRate> Ex10kgRate = boxLoad.getExport10kgBoxRate();
                    Vector<FedExBoxRate> Ex25kgRate = boxLoad.getExport25kgBoxRate();
                    Vector<FedExBoxRate> Im10kgRate = boxLoad.getImport10kgBoxRate();
                    Vector<FedExBoxRate> Im25kgRate = boxLoad.getImport25kgBoxRate();

                    VectorRate vRate=new VectorRate();
                    vRate.setExport10kgBoxRate(Ex10kgRate);
                    vRate.setExport25kgBoxRate(Ex25kgRate);
                    vRate.setImport10kgBoxRate(Im10kgRate);
                    vRate.setImport25kgBoxRate(Im25kgRate);

                    //send the 4 type of rate vector to client
                    outobject.writeObject(vRate);
                    outobject.flush();

                    //get the flateRate,AdditionalFlatRate  from the client

                    //calling the receive data function
                    receiveData();

                    // calculate the total amount
                    System.out.println("js is here");
                    System.out.println("The weight of the box is " + boxWeight);
                    System.out.println(flatRatePlusArate.getFlatRate());
                    System.out.println(flatRatePlusArate.getRateAdditionalKg());



                    amount = calculation.calculateAmount(boxWeight, flatRatePlusArate);
                    surcharge = calculation.calculateSurcharge(amount);
                    totalAmount = calculation.calculateTotalAmount(amount, surcharge);




                    //passing totalAmount to client

                    out.writeFloat(totalAmount);


                        //get the max boxNo from database

                    try
                    {
                        conn=(Connection) dbManager.getConnection();
                        System.out.println("Success");
                        Statement state = (Statement) conn.createStatement();   

                        ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("select max(boxNo) " +
                                "from provisionedbox");
                        while(result.next())
                        {
                            boxno = result.getInt("max(boxNo)");

                        }
                    }catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Fail");
                    }
                    //database/////


                    //database
                    //get the max courierBoxId from database

                    try
                    {
                        conn = (Connection) dbManager.getConnection();
                        System.out.println("Success");
                        Statement state = (Statement) conn.createStatement();   

                        ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("select max(courierBoxId) " +
                                "from provisionedbox");
                        while(result.next())
                        {
                            CourierBoxId = result.getInt("max(courierBoxId)");

                        }
                    }catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Fail");
                    }
                    //database/////

                    //get the max shipmentid from database

                    try
                    {
                        conn=(Connection) dbManager.getConnection();
                        System.out.println("Success");
                        Statement state = (Statement) conn.createStatement();   

                        ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("select max(shipmentId) " +
                                "from shipmentbox");
                        while(result.next())
                        {
                            shipmentId = result.getInt("max(shipmentId)");

                        }
                    }catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Fail");
                    }
                    //database/////

                    //plus 1 to the shipmentid 
                    shipmentId+=1;



                    //plus 1 to courierBoxId so that increment by 1
                    CourierBoxId+=1;

                    //plus 1 to boxNo so that increment by 1
                    boxno+=1;

                    System.out.println("Courierid "+CourierBoxId);
                    System.out.println("boxno "+boxno);

                    System.out.println("amount" + amount);
                    System.out.println("surcharge" + surcharge);
                    System.out.println("totalamount" + totalAmount);

                    weight = boxWeight;

                    System.out.println("weight"+ weight);


                    passBoxTypeName.setName(type);

                    System.out.println("boxtype" + passBoxTypeName);


                    //set the value into the box controller
                    box.setAmount(amount);
                    box.setSurcharge(surcharge);
                    box.setTotal(totalAmount);
                    box.setWeight(weight);
                    box.setBoxNo(boxno);
                    box.setBoxType(passBoxTypeName);
                    box.setCourierBoxId(CourierBoxId);

                    //calling database to add the provisioned box data 
                    database.AddBox(box);



                    passCountryName.setName(countryName);

                    shipBox.setAmount(totalAmount);
                    shipBox.setDestination(passCountryName);
                    shipBox.setOrigin(passCountryName);

                    //calling database to add the shipmentbox  data
                    database.addEntry(shipBox);

                    //calling database to add the courierbox data
                    database.AddCourier(shipmentId, CourierBoxId);



                    //passing data from client to GUI interface
                    callingGui.run(message1,message2,message3,clientAddress, portNumber, currentTimeStamp,countryName,type,weight,totalAmount);

                }

                // Close socket
                socket.close();

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {

                System.out.println("Server : Socket timed out!");


            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();


            }
        }



    public boolean receiveData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        while(true)
        {

            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            ObjectInputStream inobject = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("jiawei is here");
            //receive country name,type of box and weight from the client
            clientValues = (OutputCal) inobject.readObject();

            //Use the OutputCal getter to obtain the particular details
            //selected by client.
            countryName = clientValues.getSelectedCountry();
            type = clientValues.getBoxType();
            flatRatePlusArate = clientValues.getBoxRate();
            boxWeight = clientValues.getWeight();

            /*countryName = in.readUTF();*/
            /*type = in.readUTF();*/
            /*flatRatePlusArate = (FedExBoxRate)inobject.readObject();*/
            /*boxWeight = in.readFloat();*/

            System.out.println(countryName);
            System.out.println(type);
            System.out.println(flatRatePlusArate.getFlatRate());
            System.out.println(flatRatePlusArate.getRateAdditionalKg());
            System.out.println(flatRatePlusArate.getMinWeight());
            System.out.println(flatRatePlusArate.getMaxWeight());
            System.out.println(boxWeight);

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main entry point to server program
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        Thread t = new Server();
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Here is the calculation class

```
    public  class FedExSalesManager implements SalesManagerInterface
{


@Override
public float calculateAmount(float weight, FedExBoxRate boxRate)
{
    System.out.println("Hello" );
    //declaration of local variables
    float amount = 0.0f;
    float fixedWeight10kg = 10;
    float fixedWeight20kg = 25;

    System.out.println("weight is" +weight);
    System.out.println( "flatrate is" + boxRate.getFlatRate());
    System.out.println("Arate is" + boxRate.getRateAdditionalKg());

    //condition to compare the calculate method  
    if(weight > 0.10 && weight <= 10.00){
        amount = boxRate.getFlatRate();
    }

    else if(weight >= 20.00 && weight <= 25.00){
        amount = boxRate.getFlatRate();
    }

    else if(weight > 10.00 && weight < 20.00){
        float additionalWeight = weight - fixedWeight10kg;
        if(additionalWeight > 0){   
            amount = boxRate.getFlatRate() + (additionalWeight * boxRate.getRateAdditionalKg());

        }
    }

    else if(weight > 25.00 && weight <= 44.00){
        float additionalWeight = weight - fixedWeight20kg;
        if(additionalWeight > 0){   
            amount = boxRate.getFlatRate() + (additionalWeight * boxRate.getRateAdditionalKg());

        }
    }

    else{
        amount = boxRate.getFlatRate();
    }

     return amount;
}

@Override
public float calculateSurcharge(float amount) 
{
    //declaration of local variables
    float surcharge = 0.0f;

    //calculation on the surcharge
     surcharge = amount * 0.175f;

    return surcharge;
}

@Override
public float calculateTotalAmount(float amount, float surcharge)
{
    //declaration of local variables
    float totalAmount = 0.0f;

    //calculation to get the totalAmount
     totalAmount = amount + surcharge;

    return totalAmount;
}
```

}

The function that triggers the NullPointerException is this one, belonging to the server class:

```
 amount = calculation.calculateAmount(boxWeight, flatRatePlusArate);
```

Comment: Can you give the full stack trace of the exception ?

Comment: What is `null` at that line when you try to debug your program?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at server.Server.run(Server.java:294)

Comment: You gotta be clear in deciding whether you want to have the calculateAmount method as static or not.

Comment: my calculateAmount method is not static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `calculation` reference is never initialized. So it is `null` and throws the exception when you try to invoke a method on that object.